# Arrow type \Rightarrow in tikz-cd displayed not correctly

Tags: tikz-cd

I'm currently trying to draw commutative diagrams of natural transformations, to represent these I use the arrow type `\Rightarrow` of `tikz-cd`. I unfortunately incurred in the following problem: sometimes when I use this command the arrows are not displayed in the correct way.

Here's a concrete example: I wrote the following simple diagram

[image]

and this is the associated code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
u^* \phi_B \arrow[Rightarrow, dd,"u^* \eta_B" left] \arrow[rr, Rightarrow,"\gamma^{\phi}_u" above]
&  & \phi_A u^* \arrow[Rightarrow, dd,  "\eta_A u^*" right]  \\
&    & \\
u^*\nu_B \gamma_B \arrow[Rightarrow, rr,  "\gamma^{\gamma}_u  \odot \gamma^{\nu}_u" above] & & \nu_A \gamma_A u^* 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

I don't know the package `tikz-cd` very well so I don't understand why the upper arrow is drawn in this way: my guess is that the label interferes in some way with the drawing of one of the lines of the arrow but I'm not sure.

This happened non just to this particular diagram but to others as well: I write the command `\Rightarrow` but some arrows are drawn as intended while others not. This occurred to both vertical and horizontal arrows and I cannot see any pattern indicating the trouble.

So could you please let me understand what is the problem and provide a solution to it?

If you find more examples of this problem helpful just ask me to post other codes with the associated image.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What happens if you magnify the view? What's your version of `tikz-cd`?

Comment: I have no problem. Probably a problem  with the viewer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When I run your code under Linux and TeXLive 2016, it works fine: all arrows have doube lines. So it might help to upgrade. My version of `tikz-cd` is `2014/10/30 v0.9e`, and `tikz` has version `2015/08/07 v3.0.1a`.

Comment: I tried with TeX Live 2013, 2014, 2015 and 2016; the result is the same, that is, with all arrows in place. It seems a viewer problem.

Comment: @gernot: I made a clear installation of both Miktex and Texmaker  two weeks ago thus I assume it's safe to claim the problem is not that the version of tikiz and tikiz-cd are obsolete. Anyway I have your same version of tikz-cd, but I cannot find any 'tikz' in the package manager of Miktext.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s a viewer problem.

Comment: This problem has its roots in the way TikZ produces double paths, and how viewers handle it. A [discussion](https://github.com/astoff/tikz-cd/issues/14) with the maintainer of tikz-cd has resulted in a solution, see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642548/191686) for details.